# How to get from Tbilisi to Baku with a stop in Seki for one night?

Tags: driving, georgia-country, azerbaijan

We are planning a trip in Georgia/Azerbaijan and would like to visit Seki on the way from Tbilisi to Baku. We are 5 people and looking for the fastest and easiest way, possible marshrutka or taxi.

Comment: VTC: not quite WANTA, but what is being asked? With Tbilisi, Sheki, and Baku hundreds of km apart,  is OP driving, per the original tag, or taking buses/taxis? OP has not returned since posting.